# Issue with permissions after restoring Postgres DB to new server

Tags: postgresql, psql

I used following command to backup the DB on the source server:

```
pg_dump --no-acl  -h "server" --port "1234"  -U "admin"  --no-owner dbname > dbname_dump.sql
```

Then on new server I created empty database newdb and used this command to restore database

```
psql -U postgres -d newdb  -f dbname_dump.sql
```

created new user, assigned all permissions to new database. When I connected with that new user to restored database and when I wanted to do select on any table inside public schema I am getting access denied. Why?

Comment: You probably didn't grant permissions on the tables. The database is not enough. Hard to say more, because you give little information.

Comment: Could be, I used GUI and this is query that pgadmin would run on DB to set permissions

`GRANT ALL ON DATABASE "newdb" TO "app-user";`

I am expecting this is all I need.

Comment: Thank you Laurenz!! You pointed me to right direction, I am PG newbie, only worked with MSSQL so I was expecting stuff to happen same way :) I was missing this:

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA "public" TO "app-user";
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA "public" TO "app-user";
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA "migrations" TO "app-user";
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA "migrations" TO "app-user";`

Comment: This didn't help still experienced issues with permissions and ownership.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to get around the problem, in short the problem was admin user which was used for restored was owner of everything restored and creating new DB user for app usage and transferring everything to new user is a nightmare. So here are the steps to do this proper way:

1. as admin backup source database with --no-acl and --no-owner switch
2. on new server create new empty database
3. on new server create db user that will be used for app to connect to newly created database
4. grant all permissions to created user on newly created database
5. restore database with that new user into newly created database

Now app is working and I can run database migration scripts so everything is working as expected. Since I am PGSQL novice I wasn't aware only owner can make deletes or alterations on the table but after I read the manual things got much clearer.

Comment: There is also `REASSIGN OWNED`. You can also give the prospective object owner superuser temporarily for the restore.